# Statistics on documents downloaded from emails

Tags: statistics, google-analytics, download

I usually send out emails with links to document downloads. Is there any chance of registering statistics on those using Google Analytics?

Answer (score 2):

Javascript and Google Analytics doesn't work in HTML emails, so you can't measure the clicks on those directly.

If you use an email service provider, like Mailchimp or one of the many others, they *will* provide click-tracking at not additional cost, so you could consider that. Most ESPs will have a free or freemium plan you can try.

Otherwise, you can do the following:

1. Route all clicks through a script that counts the clicks. Pros: accurate count. Cons: custom development, re-inventing the wheel.
2. Direct all the clicks to a landing page that has Google Analytics implemented. Pros: easy implementation, no custom development. Cons: extra click will lead to some dropoff.

I would recommend an email service provider. Besides the click-tracking, it will give you much better deliverability, testing tools, and reporting options.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an intermediary page that sends off the GA Tracking Beacon before redirecting to the download. This could either be done using JavaScript that works in a similar way to outbound link tracking or using a `meta-refresh`. Either way you would want to put a message on the page stating that the download will start shortly and a redirect link in case something goes wrong.